# Group a dataframe and calculate normalised standard deviation by group?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
           product  cost_per_quantity
12779  0101010G0BB         160.788357
12653  0101010G0BC         179.493956
10390  0101010I0AA           0.425916
20361  0101010I0AA           0.603650
22504  0101010I0AA           0.633082
```

created with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'product': ['0101010G0BB', '0101010G0BC', '0101010I0AA', '0101010I0AA', '0101010I0AA'], 'cost_per_quantity': [160.788357, 179.493956, 0.425916, 0.603650, 0.633082]})
```

Now I want to find the products with the maximum variation in `cost_per_quantity`.

So for example, I'd like to examine the product `0101010I0AA` and find the normalised standard deviation for `cost_per_quantity` across its three entries, and then compare it with normalised standard deviation for other products.

What's the best way to approach this? I tried:

```
df1 = df.groupby('product').agg(np.std)
```

but that just gives me a bunch of `NaN`s.

Comment: @ayhan thanks! I think it's returning raw s.d. though, not normalised - any idea how I might go about returning normalised s.d.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For aggregation `df.groupby('product').agg(np.std)` is correct but for 1-observation groups this returns `NaN` as the sample standard deviation cannot be calculated for 1-observation groups. Numpy default for standard deviation is population standard deviation but I guess Pandas is overriding that.

You can go with the population standard deviation to get 0 for those groups.

If you want to see the relative deviation with respect to the mean, you can use [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation):

```
df.groupby('product').apply(lambda x: np.std(x) / np.mean(x))
```

Now that `np.std` is in a lambda function, it behaves as expected.